# Add jar file to Maven Reactor modules list

Tags: maven, maven-reactor

I have 3 Modules (ModuleA,ModuleB,ModuleC). I extracted ModuleC as an independent jar (which contains db scripts).

In pom.xml I am trying to do something like below,

```
<project ...>
......
<modules>
 <module>ModuleA</module>
 <module>ModuleB</module>
</modules>
....
</project>
```

How can I include that JAR module (ModuleC) inside the reactor, so that it builds just like a normal module. If I add it as a dependency, how the scripts inside that would be executed during a profile call?

In addition to the above I also have profiles as shown below,

```
<profile>
  <id>runScript</id>

  <modules>
    <module>parent/child/ModuleA</module>
    <module>parent/child/ModuleB</module>
  </modules>
</profile>
```

I need to add ModuleC (JAR) to this profile.So that it gets executed when profile is called.

Any ideas please?

Comment: try rephrasing the question. Also, what do you mean by _"How can I include that JAR module inside the reactor?"_ Why can't you add the third party JAR as dependency?

Comment: rephrased, please see if that makes sense... also its NOT a third party JAR I'm trying to use. Its my project module which was made as a independent component in Git.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder, What do you want to achieve by adding a jar as a dependency ? maven builds are for creating jar,war etc executable files. If you already have a .jar , its use less to add it in modules. I would suggest add .jar as a dependency in  pom of the particular project.

In `<modules>` tag, you can only add maven projects , not jars directly.
Dependencies are after all for this purpose only.
Hovever if you still want to do ,   Add it as a dependency in main project.

```
<project ...>
......
<modules>
 <module>ModuleA</module>
 <module>ModuleB</module>
</modules>
....
<dependencies>      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>{groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>{artifactId}</artifactId>
            <version>{version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>{scope}</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: What I have is a database script in ModuleC which needs to be executed  when I call say "integration" or "runScript" profiles. Would dependency help that cause?

Comment: you have ModuleC as a maven project or .jar?

Comment: Doshi: As mentioned I have db scripts inside that JAR which needs to be executed when I call a particular profile. Though I'm not keen on adding it as a module, I'm just assuming providing it as module would help that cause, and I understood it's not going to help. Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: Its a maven project and the artifact I get out of that is a .jar.

Comment: When you build using maven , It only compiles all of your java and other files and creates a jar.Its like executing **javac** command which will generate class files only. As far as I know, To run the script , you need to explicitly run the jar file. Hope this helps.

Comment: ok, finally here is what I am trying to do. Make a *source.jar out of ModuleC and then refer it in the POM using copy-dependencies using classifier as "source" and unpack in a location within the project. Refer the new location in <modules> tag for the reactor to pickup.